# Android - what is the name of the current voice recognition service

Tags: android, service, voice-recognition

I think i get Current Voice recognition using below code.

```
String serviceComponent = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE);
```

should do it, but `Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE` is not recognized.

Comment: This? https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result should be the default provider. If the list is empty, there are none:

```
        final List<ResolveInfo> services = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(
                new Intent(RecognitionService.SERVICE_INTERFACE), 0);

        String packageName = "";
        String serviceName = "";

        for (final ResolveInfo info : services) {
                packageName = info.serviceInfo.packageName;
                serviceName = info.serviceInfo.name;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking everywhere for this answer!